# no resizable in popup window dont work in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, resize, window

i try to open new window with javascript window.open func,

and add `'resizable = no'` parameter,

in ie its work , but in firefox it allow to resize

how can i block it in firefox ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popup window is always resizable in Mozilla, Opera.

Check this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html):

> The popup is always resizable in Mozilla, Opera and Konqueror. When making the popup resizable in Safari, actually resizing it makes the popup jump to a width of ca. 400px, which cannot be decreased.

Answer (score 0):

Try without spaces, if you don't do that already:

```
resizable=no
```

Answer (score 0):

Another try:

http://www.technipages.com/firefox-prevent-sites-from-disabling-window-resize.html

You can prevent it in firefox, do you have that on? I know I would.

Comment: i think its bug in fire fox that not fix yet,
http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=el&comments_parentId=120127&forumId=1

Comment: Well, for me it's a feature, as i said :) Anyway, thanks for the info

Answer (score -2):

Did you consider it is really annoying for users not being able to resize their browser window? I would suggest you find another solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: did you consider it is really annoying when users don't answer the question? I would suggest you answer the question