# How stop resizing...?with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How stop resizing...

`resizable=no` doesnt work help me guys!

```
window.open('http://www.artechin.com/emre/puanhesap.html', 'puan', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=500,height=423,resizable=no');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [no resizable in popup window dont work in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666219/no-resizable-in-popup-window-dont-work-in-firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They stopped that with Firefox 3 - this could have been security problems, the idea nowadays is to not hide the URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at the page in FireFox 3+ it ignores the resizable setting and will always allow you to resize the window.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.open#Window_functionality_features

Notably Mozilla recommend that the resizable attribute is always set to yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox, than is because of default setting of that browser.
[forum post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1137205)