# resizable=no is not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I have following snippet:

```
window.open("http://www.stackoveflow.com","_blank","toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=0, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
```

It is perfectly working in IE. But when I run this on Mozilla, I still be able to resize the window. Which should not be the case.

Can anyone please suggest on this?

Comment: This is by design: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open#Window_functionality_features

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666219/no-resizable-in-popup-window-dont-work-in-firefox

Comment: Is there any other approach to make this non resizable in Firefox? @Blender

Comment: @vkreddy: Nope, the Firefox developers disabled it on purpose.

Comment: And one more thing,   'window.open(" ","name","toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=0, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");'    The new popup window has following properties.. In IE : Address bar not showing URL. But Firefox displaying Address bar as same as Parent window.  How can i make it invisible ? i tried by giving titlebar=0 but its not working. @Blender

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla made some helpful changes for users, and giving the user the ability to resize is one of them. See [this helpfull answer from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216208/i-dont-want-pop-up-window-to-be-resizable#answer-8216251)